# Whats the correct code for Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I use following code:

Create a retry policy, when error, retry after 1 second, then wait 3 seconds, then 5 seconds. based on Azure SLA, retry within 10 seconds must success (No throttled, I sure this. because error even happens on unique partition and table which no traffic yet)

```
var retryStrategy = new Incremental(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
var FaultHandlingRetryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);
```

Then I use this code to get data

```
FaultHandlingRetryPolicy .ExecuteAction(() =>
        {
            var results = (from q in Query select new q).ToList();
        });
```

I DO NOT KNOW if its retried or not, because the error log not shown

Errors:

```
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 70.37.127.112:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.Execute()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteAction>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 func)
```

Please let me know if this code will retry, thanks

Comment: btw, I have an old thread at MS for this as well http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/b55d0126-f80b-4df2-bcb6-8b5da37c51ff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you setup a retry policy, you specify the class that will control the retires, in your case it is `StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy`.

Each time an exception is thrown inside the `ExecuteAction()` method, this class will decide if a retry is possible or not. For instance some exceptions are transient, so it's not worth retrying them.

To actually track the number of retries, you can use code like this:

```
FaultHandlingRetryPolicy.Retrying += (obj, eventArgs) =>
            {
                Console.Writeline("Retrying, CurrentRetryCount = {0} , Exception = {1}", eventArgs.CurrentRetryCount, eventArgs.LastException.Message);
            };
```

**Update**

You can create your own error handling strategy like so and use it in-place of the standard one. **BUT** you'll have to tune the errors to fit with your scenario, these worked for me.

```
    public class CustomSqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy : ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy
    {
        private readonly SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy _normalStrategy =
            new SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy();

        public bool IsTransient(Exception ex)
        {
            if (_normalStrategy.IsTransient(ex))
                return true;

            //do our custom logic
            if (ex is SqlException)
            {
                var sqEx = ex as SqlException;
                if (sqEx.Message.Contains("The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding") ||
                    sqEx.Message.Contains("An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host") ||
                    sqEx.Message.Contains("The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again") ||
                    sqEx.Message.Contains("Timeout expired") ||
                    sqEx.Message.Contains("was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim") ||
                    sqEx.Message.Contains("A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server"))
                {                        
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank for the way to track retry. But still, whats the correct code to retry? And why transient error is not worth retry, I think only permanent error like wrong account etc not worth retry

Comment: I guess it doesn't consider the error `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 70.37.127.112:443` a transient error, i.e. one that should only happen every once in a while.

Comment: I decompiled the `StorageTransientErrorDetectionStrategy` class in Reflector (http://www.reflector.net/) to see how it determined which errors were transient or not.

Comment: the error is not just happen once  awhile, it happens lots, consider I only query average 1 per second, still get the error like once few hours.